# How to clear windows `push` state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `history.push()` state to prevent the web page by the user for client requirements.

for that, I use the following code :

```
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
    $(window).on('popstate', function () {
        history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});
```

works fine. But in the next page, I am not able to use the back button, since the above code sets in global space.
so how to clear the history push state any make browser again in the normal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does _to prevent the web page by the user_ mean? You are breaking the back button and now ask how to not break the back button

Comment: this are all about the matter of client. basically my app has multiple entry point. some page require to prevent some pages not. some condition allows  some condition deneys

Answer (score 0):

Ideally `pushState` is used to push a new URL to the address bar.

You need to add a listener to the `popstate` event.

This will be when you click the back button after pushing a state, the page receives the event.

In it you need to replace the page contents with the correct page.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {    
    if ( event && event.state ) {
        location.reload(); 
    }
}
```